# how to delete oracle ewallet.p12?

Tags: oracle, windows-10, oracle19c

I have completely removed all oracle 19.c things in windows 10 but I could not delete the folder existing in drive C and the reason is ewallet.p12,
by the way, normal ways like setting the permission security access to everyone didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually there are two files that cannot be removed after uninstalling oracle 19c; The one you mention (ewallet.p12) and cwallet.sso.
I also tried permission security access and didn't work. Beside that, there is no registry key to delete.
I only managed to remove these two files with [unlocker](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml).